# Overleaf wordcount

Tags: overleaf, word-count, texcount

Performing a wordcount on a latex document on overleaf produces a table of the form:

Total Words:10000

Headers:5

Math Inline:100

Math Display:10

What I'd like to know is if these categories are disjoint. In particular, does the "total words" count  include the "Math Inline" or "Math Display" count, i.e. is "Total Words" the number of english language words excluding all mathematical equations and symbols? I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Given that your query appears to be rather Overleaf-sprecific and would appear to have litttle to do with TeX, LaTeX, and friends, have you considered addressing your query to the Overleaf Helpdesk? I hear their technical support staff are top notch.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll do that :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Overleaf currently uses `texcount` for word counts, so the way things are counted is determined by `texcount`.

They are disjoint, the "total words" count does not include the totals from the other categories.

Test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Word $x$
\begin{equation}
y
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`texcount` Output:

```
% texcount main-demo.tex 
File: main-demo.tex
Encoding: ascii
Words in text: 1
Words in headers: 1
Words outside text (captions, etc.): 0
Number of headers: 1
Number of floats/tables/figures: 0
Number of math inlines: 1
Number of math displayed: 1
```

Overleaf Output:

```
Word Count
Total Words:1
Headers:1
Math Inline:1
Math Display:1
```